# Math equation sign $$ is not disappearing in r markdown output

Tags: r, latex, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am trying to write a distribution using matrices.

My knowledge is that to display mathematical symbols using `LaTeX` syntax, I need to use `$$` signs. Thus I wrote,

```
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_i \\
\epsilon_i
\end{pmatrix}
\sim
N\begin{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix},

        \begin{pmatrix}
        3 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
```

This works well but I realized that `$$` is not needed in this case. `$$` is left out in the output file. So I had to delete `$$` at both ends to remove them in the output file.

However, this disables mathematical equation block in the `Rmd` file and as a result, preview of the syntax is not showing anymore and it is more confusing to read `Rmd` file since there is no distinction from normal texts.

Why do I not need to specify `$$` in this case? 
and why is `$$` not disappearing in the output file?

Comment: What do you mean with "This works well but I realized that $$ is not needed in this case. "? Why it is not needed?

Comment: It means that the code returns output properly without $$.

Comment: #dww, if I remove 'align', matrices and N and ~ signs do not align properly. What can I do to fix them?

Comment: Do you want to convert to PDF or HTML?